# Execute Postgres Trigger on an entire transaction and not for each update operation

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I was wondering if it is possible to force the execution of a trigger in PostgreSql based on a transaction.

I am updating the records from a python script(from within a for loop). There is a trigger which inserts a record into the table on update operation. Now, I only want to insert one record based on the entire transaction and not for every record which I am updating from within a python script.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: If there are a bunch of updates statements between BEGIN and COMMIT, I only want to call my trigger once for this. Is there a way to detect such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little clunky, but you can do this with a conditional trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t
AFTER UPDATE ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (IsFirstCallForThisTransaction())
EXECUTE PROCEDURE MyTrigger();
```

The tricky bit is defining `IsFirstCallForThisTransaction()`. Internally, it needs to set a flag somewhere, but we also need a guarantee that this flag is scoped to the current transaction.

One option is to use [`SET LOCAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) to assign a [custom configuration variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-custom.html). You can initialise this variable by putting this line server's `postgresql.conf` file:

```
my_vars.trigger_called_in_current_transaction = false
```

Or alternatively, attach a default to the database in question:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET my_vars.trigger_called_in_current_transaction = false;
```

Then the function would look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsFirstCallForThisTransaction() RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF current_setting('my_vars.trigger_called_in_current_transaction')::boolean THEN
    RETURN false;
  ELSE
    SET LOCAL my_vars.trigger_called_in_current_transaction TO true;
    RETURN true;
  END IF;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```